# OSPF with Multiple VLANs

Tags: routing, vlan, ospf, security

In a Level 3 network with multiple, isolated (i.e. [firewalled](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16736/ospf-with-multiple-vlans#comment24651_16736)) VLANs, how does OSPF interact with the VLANs?

Specifically:

1. Is it standard to use multiple OSPF instances, i.e. one per VLAN?
2. If the VLANs have the same topology, can a single OSPF instance be used?

Comment: What do you mean by "independent?"  If there are L3 interfaces (SVI) on the VLANs, they are treated like any other router interface for OSPF.

Comment: @Ron, I mean there is to be no traffic passing from one VLAN to another. They are "firewalled" from each other in the strongest sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is it standard to use multiple OSPF instances, i.e. one per (isolated) VLAN?

This is a standard approach, only so far as you're using [MPLS VPN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10848160/667301) and/or [vrf-lite](http://packetlife.net/blog/2009/apr/30/intro-vrf-lite/) to isolate your vlan routing information; read more about OSPF in the context of MPLS VPN and VRF-lite [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/mp_l3_vpns/configuration/xe-3s/mp-l3-vpns-xe-3s-book/mp-vpn-ospf-pe-ce-support.html).

One of the main reasons for using multiple OSPF instances is for controlling LSA flooding (that assumes you couldn't otherwise [control LSA distribution](http://blog.ine.com/2009/08/17/ospf-route-filtering-demystified/))<sup>Note 1</sup>.

> 2. If the VLANs have the same topology, can a single OSPF instance be used?

In cases where you don't have to isolate vlans for security purposes, a single OSPF instance can and *should* be used. Most of the time, you should avoid multiple OSPF instances.  Some exceptions:

- When your vlans are assigned to different customers use MPLS VPN (which uses BGP as the underlying control-plane)
- When you are trying to filter LSAs (as noted above)

---

<sup>Note 1</sup>As an aside, I personally dislike the whole concept of filtering OSPF LSAs; address summarization is perfectly normal... blocking an LSA that should otherwise be flooded makes things more complicated to troubleshoot.  OSPF loves to flood LSAs; in many cases people who are (ab)using OSPF for route/LSA control should be offload the work to a protocol which was designed for controlling routes (such as iBGP).